# Why Avada theme page editor not working.?

Tags: wordpress, themes

I am trying to edit page but it gives me the following error:

> This site can’t be reached
> The webpage at "https:___" might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
> ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

when I disable Avada Core plugin page editor is working.
I tried and old version of Avada but is not working. I tried an old version of Wordpress as well, but the page editor still does not work

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this problem with this response from Avada support:

ThemeFusion_Support
ThemeFusion_Support AUTHOR TEAM

about 6 hours ago Flag
Hi

If you are using GoDaddy then please ask them to add the following code in your htaccess. Code here

Please do ensure you backup your site before you do so.

If you require further assistance or have any further questions, please create a support ticket using the link below and our support team will gladly assist you

Click Here To Get Avada Support

We look forward to helping you!

Comment: Code here is:
# BEGIN Line too long fix

<IfModule mod_substitute.c>
SubstituteMaxLineLength 10M
</IfModule>
# END Line too long fix

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Toni! This fixed my problem with Avada theme admin page editor on GoDaddy hosting. In the htaccess file I had to use line breaks for the code to work. So it looks like this:

```
# BEGIN Line too long fix 
<IfModule mod_substitute.c> 
SubstituteMaxLineLength 10M 
</IfModule> 
# END
```

Comment: If you're getting 200 Ok error while trying to open avada forms or page editor then this is the solution. Thank you.